How to Ensure install(RUNTIME_DEPENDENCIES) Finds Shared Libraries Without Specifying DIRECTORIES?
I'm working on a CMake project with the following structure:

A/CMakeLists.txt: Generates an executable and links against B and C static libraries.
A/B/CMakeLists.txt: Builds the B static library, which depends on dep1.so (not in the system path).
A/C/CMakeLists.txt: Builds the C static library, which depends on dep2.so (not in the system path).

Here’s the relevant CMake code:
# A/B/CMakeLists.txt
add_library(B STATIC b.cpp)
target_link_libraries(B PRIVATE /path/to/dep1.so)
set_target_properties(B PROPERTIES BUILD_RPATH "/path/to/dep1")

# A/C/CMakeLists.txt
add_library(C STATIC c.cpp)
target_link_libraries(C PRIVATE /path/to/dep2.so)
set_target_properties(C PROPERTIES BUILD_RPATH "/path/to/dep2")

# A/CMakeLists.txt
add_executable(MyExecutable main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(MyExecutable B C)

install(TARGETS MyExecutable
        RUNTIME_DEPENDENCIES
        # DIRECTORIES "/path/to/dep1" "/path/to/dep2"  # I want to avoid this
        RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
        LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
        ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib)

The Issue:
install(RUNTIME_DEPENDENCIES) fails to find dep1.so and dep2.so unless I explicitly specify the DIRECTORIES option, which I want to avoid.
Questions:

What paths does CMake search by default when using install(RUNTIME_DEPENDENCIES)?
How can I configure B and C to automatically find these dependencies without specifying DIRECTORIES?

Any guidance would be appreciated!

Why do you set BUILD_RPATH for your targets? By default, CMake automatically adds to RPATH directories, where linked libraries are located. No need to add those directories explicitly. Or have you disabled automatically generation of RPATH by setting CMAKE_SKIP_BUILD_RPATH variable or similar?

@Tsyvarev Thank you for pointing that out. I haven’t set CMAKE_SKIP_BUILD_RPATH or similar variables that would disable RPATH generation. However, install(RUNTIME_DEPENDENCIES) still fails to find dep1.so and dep2.so without specifying the DIRECTORIES option. Do you have any ideas why this might be happening?

this works for me set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE).   but is there any way?

"What paths does CMake search by default when using install(RUNTIME_DEPENDENCIES)" - CMake searches the same paths as a runtime linker which is automatically used when you run your executable. So, if your executable in the build tree could be run, then CMake should successfully find all its dependencies. And by default CMake automatically adds to RPATH all directories, which are sufficient for running an executable.

The variable CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH primarily affects an executable in the install tree. Since it helps you in fixing the problem with the executable in the build tree, it seems you have set the variable CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH, which makes RPATH of the executable in the build tree to be same as in the install tree. Setting this variable disables autogenerating RPATH in the build tree, unless you set CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH variable.

Note, that your settings of BUILD_RPATH property has no effect, because static libraries has no RPATH. Such settings are also ignored if you have CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH variable to be set.

Thank you. I can't find any better way except CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH .

Just remove setting of CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH from your code, and CMake itself will adjust RPATH for the executable in the binary tree. With such executable install(RUNTIME_DEPENDENCIES) will work without manual interventions.
